# dynamic table and button creation in asp.net

Tags: vb.net

I have created a dynamic table using for loop condition.In which it has a button while i click a specific button it should open a file.But in my coding it is opening a file button in the last row.

```
 If Not IsPostBack Then
      txtlogsdate.Text = FormatDate(Now)
 End If

 Try
     trViewlogs.Visible = True
     lbllogs.Visible = False
     lbllogname.Visible = True
     RT1.Visible = False
     pb.Visible = False

     Dim d1 As DateTime = txtlogsdate.Text
     Dim dd As String = d1.ToString("dd")
     Dim mm As String = d1.ToString("MM")
     Dim yy As String = d1.ToString("yy")
     Dim d2 As String = yy & "" & mm & "" & dd

     Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~\logs"))
     Dim files As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.log")

     Dim tab As New Table()
     tab.CellPadding = 0
     tab.CellSpacing = 0
     tab.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Double
     tab.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-left: 0.5px; width: 800px;")

     Dim row As New TableRow()                
     Dim headerCell1 As New TableHeaderCell()
     headerCell1.Text = "Logs"

     headerCell1.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-left: 0.5px; height: 20px;")
     headerCell1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue
     headerCell1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
     row.Controls.Add(headerCell1)
     tab.Controls.Add(row)


     Dim headerCell2 = New TableHeaderCell()

     headerCell2.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-left: 0.5px; height: 20px;")
     headerCell2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue
     headerCell2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
     headerCell2.Text = "Download"
     row.Controls.Add(headerCell2)
     tab.Controls.Add(row)

     For i As Integer = 0 To files.Length - 1
         Dim a As String = files(i).ToString.Replace("Event-", "")
         Dim c As String = a.Substring(0, 6)
         Dim sw As String

         If d2 = c Then
             sw = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(_
               GetWebSitePhysicalRoot & "\logs\" & files(i).ToString)

             lbllogname.Text = files(i).ToString                     
             lbllogname.Visible = False

             row = New TableRow()

             If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                 row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
             Else
                 row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue
             End If
             Dim cell As New TableCell()
             cell.Text = lbllogname.Text
             'cell.Width = New Unit("1000px")
             cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
             row.Controls.Add(cell)

             Dim cell2 As New TableCell()                              

             Dim bt As New Button
             bt.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid

             bt.Text = files(i).ToString

             AddHandler bt.Click, AddressOf bt_Click

             cell2.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
             cell2.Controls.Add(bt)
             row.Controls.Add(cell2)
             tab.Controls.Add(row)
             Panel1.Controls.Add(tab)
         End If

     Next i
     If lbllogname.Text = "" Then
         lbllogname.Text = "No Logs to Display !"
     End If

     Session("pageurl") = ""
     Session("pagecount") = ""
     ib.SetInfo("Reports > View Logs", Infobar.InfoTypes.Caption)
     Dim mi As Integer = GetQueryStringToInt("menuindex", 1)
     If Not IsPostBack Then
         leftmenu1.AddItem("View Logs", _
         GetWebSiteUrlRoot & "/staff_rpt.aspx?rpt=logs&page=1&menuindex=" & mi)
     End If

  Catch ex As Exception
        WriteLog(LogWriter.EventType.eError, ex.StackTrace.ToString)
  End Try

 Protected Sub bt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
          ByVal e As System.EventArgs
    Dim a As String
    a = lbllogname.Text
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & a)
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/logs/" & a))
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the dynamic table structure you have built in your code, then you need to uniquely name each button in each row; otherwise the button click handler (`bt_Click`) cannot figure out the correct row to open the file in, because they are all called the same and will use the last one.

Since you want a table structure, then I suggest you use the `GridView` server control, as it will provide similar output, but provide the ability to use templating to name the controls of each row the same, but allow for you to differentiate individual rows when a click event happens.